# SQLite: Insert current timestamp with milliseconds precision

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to insert the current timestamp into SQLite:

```
CREATE TABLE test (timestamp DATETIME);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(datetime('now'));
```

This does create the timestamp, but only with seconds-precision (the timestamp looks like `2013-12-17 07:02:20`). Is it possible to add the milliseconds, as well?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Date and time functions reference](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) says `datetime(timestring, [modifiers...])` is equivalent to `strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', timestring, [modifiers...])`.

If you want fractional seconds you must use `%f` not `%S`. So use `strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', 'now')` .

```
CREATE TABLE test (timestamp DATETIME);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', 'now'));
```

Comment: Actually, I use `replace(strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%f', 'now'), '.', '')` as store it as numeric.